# grunt-dom-munger - n error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appcss' of undefined)

Tags: gruntjs

I am building angular application via grunt and are facing problem in grunt-dom-munger

here is my grunt file config settings

```
dom_munger: {
            read: {
                options: {
                    read: [
                        {
                            selector: 'script', // script[data-concat!="false"]
                            attribute: 'src',
                            writeto: 'appjs',
                            isPath: true
                        },
                        {
                            selector: 'link[rel="stylesheet"]', // link[rel="stylesheet"][data-concat!="false"]
                            attribute: 'href',
                            writeto: 'appcss',
                            isPath: true
                        }
                    ]
                },


        src: 'app/index.html'
        },
        update: {
            options: {
                remove: ['script[data-remove!="false"]', 'link[data-remove!="false"]'],
                append: [
                    {
                        selector: 'body',
                        html: '<script src="app.full.min.js"></script><script src="config.js"></script>'
                    },
                    {
                        selector: 'head',
                        html: '<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.full.min.css">'
                    }
                ]
            },
            src: 'app/index.html',
            dest: 'dist/app/index.html'
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        main: {
            src: ['temp/app.css', '<%= dom_munger.data.appcss %>'],
            dest: 'dist/app/assets/css/app.full.min.css'
        }
    },
    concat: {
        main: {
            src: ['<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>', '<%= ngtemplates.main.dest %>'],
            dest: 'temp/app.full.js'
        }
    },
```

when i run grunt build, the following warning / error thrown

```
 Running "cssmin:main" (cssmin) task
 Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appcss' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appcss' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appcss' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    Warning: The "path" argument must be of type string Used --force, continuing.

    Running "concat:main" (concat) task
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appjs' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appjs' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'appjs' of undefined). Used --force, continuing.
    File temp/app.full.js created.
```

Note: my source app files located in /app directory and destination folder is /dist/

Can anyone help me where i am making mistake.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

We faced same problem at build time.
After so much R&D we got solution.
please change line no **42** in "node_modules/grunt-dom-munger/tasks/dom_munger.js" file.

```
var relativeTo = path.dirname(grunt.file.expand(f));
```

To

```
var relativeTo = path.dirname(grunt.file.expand(f)[0]);
```